# Instantiating a Serializer consisting of multiple ModelSerializers - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have two ModelSerializers:

```
class VariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Variant
         fields = (
             'id',
             'name',
             ... and so on)
```

and

```
class PictureItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PictureItem
        fields = (
            'id',
            ... and so forth)
```

What I want to do is to return a JSON including a single instance of the VariantSerializer, and multiple instances of the PictureItemSerializer.

I created another serializer as such:

```
class PictureItemUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    variant = VariantSerializer()
    pictureItems = PictureItemSerializer(many=True)
```

But I'm having difficulties in instantiating this "combination" of a serializer if you will.

This does not work:

```
p = PictureItemUploadSerializer()
p.variant = variant_serializer
p.pictureItems = picture_item_serializer
return Response(p.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

as it yields empty data:

```
{
    "variant": {
        "name": ""
    },
    "pictureItems": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data dictionary to the serializer when you are creating an instance of the serializer.

Lets say `variant_data` contains data for `Variant` model and `picture_items_data` contains the list of `PictureItem` model data.

Create a `data` dictionary containing them.

```
data = {'variant': variant_data, 'pictureItems': picture_items_data}
```

Then pass this data to the serializer.

```
p = PictureItemUploadSerializer(data=data) # pass the data dictionary
p.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # check if serializer is valid
return Response(p.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) # return response
```